# Палиндром и метод replace

Tags: python, python-3.x

Делаю скрипт "Проверка на палиндром".Нужно чтоб скрипт проверял текст на наличие спец.символов, а за тем убирал их если они были найдены.Вот собственно код:

```py
text = input(" --> ")
array = ('.',',',' ','!')

for i in array:
    if text.find(i):
        text.replace(i,'')

if text.lower() == text[::-1].lower():
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```

Программа работает,но скрипт не убирает спец.символы из текста,есть подозрения на 2 или 6 строки.Хелп ми!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`text.replace(i,'')` *возвращает* измененную строку, но сама переменная `text` остается неизменной

но я бы делал это с использованием регулярных выражений:

```
import re
import string


def is_palindrome(s):
    pat = f"[\s{re.escape(string.punctuation)}]"
    s = re.sub(pat, "", s).lower()
    return s == s[::-1]
```

---

тесты:

```
In [8]: is_palindrome("Assa")
Out[8]: True

In [9]: is_palindrome(".A-s,sa!")
Out[9]: True

In [10]: is_palindrome("Massa")
Out[10]: False
```

Comment: Ведь строки в python неизменяемы,вот же я додик,спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Незнание синтаксиса губит,не обязательно проверять наличие запрещенных символов в строке,можно сразу же их перебирать в цикле `for` и замещать методом `text.replace()`.Если символа в строке не окажется,ошибки не будет!Вот,собственно,код:

```py
text = input(' --> ')
array = (',','.','!',' ')

for i in array:
    text = text.replace(i,'')

if text.lower() == text[::-1].lower():
    print('isPalindrom')
else:
    print('isNotPalindrom')
```